# How to trigger google places autocomplete programmatically for integration testing?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/21jA_Ean1xg) is almost what I'm looking for:

```
script = "$('#my_input').val('Paris').trigger('focus').trigger('keydown');"
page.execute_script script
```

Input field gets selected, 'Paris' is written in it, keydown is pressed, google places autocomplete appears.

But nothing happens when i raise mouseenter/click events.

Tried changing class in selector to `.pac-item` like this (since `ul.autocomplete` does not exist):

```
$('.pac-item a:contains(\"Paris\")')
```

How to select one of the results from google places autocomplete programmatically using javascript (+jquery)?

Comment: Why not use the Maps API to get a JSON result set from a query? If you ask to geolocate 'Paris' it will return with several results including their lat/lon such as `{[city:'Paris', country:'France'], [city:'Paris', country:'USA', state:'Texas'] ...}`

Comment: @Chloe I'm trying to write an integration test. It needs to be as close to user interaction as possible (would mock request to googleplaces once i get that far). Getting json from maps API is not a problem.

Comment: @ArnisL. did you ever figure out how to mock click events on place autocomplete results?